# Android Studio. Errors after moving the folder

Tags: android

The application project is located on Disk C:
I copied the project to the D: drive, I run the project from the D: drive and an error appears.
I run the project from drive C: and the error is not there.

There is the same project on disk C: and D:.

How to fix so that the project from the D: drive opens without error?

```
Multiple build operations failed.
    Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':google_mobile_ads:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':url_launcher_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':webview_flutter_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\Android\aplikacje\aplikacje\app-jPL\app\Source File V_3.0.5\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\atom\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.17\android.
```

I did Rebuild Project and Invalidate Cache with a check mark:

- Clear file system...
- Clear FCS...
- Delete embedded...

and nothing helped.

Comment: did you sync the project with gradle files after moving it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

1. Terminal: flutter pub cache repair
2. Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean
3. Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Pub Get
4. Build -> Flutter -> Flutter APK